# Cannot validate credit card using Active Merchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemerchant

I have problem with validate credit card details using Active Merchant gem. When I try insert new payment, always have error:  `The credit card you provided was declined. 2  Please double check your information and try again.`. This mean that, response isn't success. I don't have idea why. I use code from tutorial: [Active Merchant Tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/credit-card-processing-with-active-merchant)

**payment.rb**

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "active_merchant/billing/rails"

 attr_accessor :card_security_code
 attr_accessor :credit_card_number
 attr_accessor :expiration_month
 attr_accessor :expiration_year

 validates :first_name, presence: true
 validates :last_name, presence: true
 validates :card_security_code, presence: true
 validates :credit_card_number, presence: true
 validates :expiration_month, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 12 }
 validates :expiration_year, presence: true
 validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }

 validate :valid_card

 def credit_card
   ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
     number:              credit_card_number,
     verification_value:  card_security_code,
     month:               expiration_month,
     year:                expiration_year,
     first_name:          first_name,
     last_name:           last_name
   )
 end

 def valid_card
   if !credit_card.valid?
     errors.add(:base, "The credit card information you provided is not valid.  Please double check the information you provided and then try again.")
     false
   else
     true
   end
 end

 def process
   if valid_card
     response = GATEWAY.authorize(amount * 100, credit_card)
     if response.success?
       transaction = GATEWAY.capture(amount * 100, response.authorization)
       if !transaction.success?
         errors.add(:base, "The credit card you provided was declined.  Please double check your information and try again.") and return
         false
       end
       update_columns({authorization_code: transaction.authorization, success: true})
       true
     else
       errors.add(:base, "The credit card you provided was declined. 2  Please double check your information and try again.") and return
       false
     end
   end
 end
end
```

**initializers/activemerchant.rb**

```
if Rails.env == "development"
  #we set up a log file
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::FirstdataE4Gateway.wiredump_device = File.open(Rails.root.join("log","active_merchant.log"), "a+")
  # enable logging
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::FirstdataE4Gateway.wiredump_device.sync = true
  # we wish to use the test version of the gateway
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

  login = ENV["GATEWAY_ID"]
  password = ENV["GATEWAY_PASSWORD"]
elsif Rails.env == "production"
  login = ENV["GATEWAY_ID"]
  password = ENV["GATEWAY_PASSWORD"]
end
GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::FirstdataE4Gateway.new({
      login: login,
      password: password
})
```

GATEWAY_ID and GATEWAY_PASSWORD data I store in .env file.
Update:
If I use response.inspect, displays this:

```
#<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0x007f4d0bfc8d98 @params={"transaction_approved"=>"false", "error_number"=>"401", "error_description"=>"Unauthorized Request. Bad or missing credentials."}, @message="Unauthorized Request. Bad or missing credentials.", @success=false, @test=true, @authorization="", @fraud_review=nil, @error_code=nil, @avs_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil}, @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Unauthorized Request. Bad or missing credentials.
```

This suggests that maybe your login or password variables are not being set correctly? Have you made sure that the environment variables GATEWAY_ID and GATEWAY_PASSWORD are set correctly in both development and production environments?